# PowerPoint and R: How to "plot" .ppt slides in quartz window?

Tags: r, powerpoint

Any suggestions on how to use R to present .ppt slides. I am giving a presentation and instead of switching back and forth between PowerPoint and R I'd like to be able to present some .ppt slides within R itself. I've seen lots of talk about going from R to PowerPoint but not much for going the other way.

Thoughts?

Comment: Your question is ill-defined. Do you want to show R doing things dynamically?  Do you want to display static images (aka "slides")? There's nothing magic about a PowerPoint display -- you could easily tell R to load and display a series of , e.g., png images derived from some slideshow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting the ppt as images would make handling them in R

Comment: Hey, that's what I said :-)

Comment: Thanks. I was being a little dense the morning I wrote the original question. What @Cilvic and Carl Witthoft posted is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the package ReporteRs:

```
library( ReporteRs )

pptx.file = "presentation.pptx"
# Creation of doc, a pptx object (default template)
doc = pptx( )

doc = addSlide( doc, "Two Content" )
# add into doc first 10 lines of iris
doc = addTitle( doc, "First 10 lines of iris" )
doc = addTable( doc, iris[1:10,] )

# add text with stylename "Normal" into doc (and an empty line just before)
doc = addParagraph( doc, value = c("", "Hello World!"), stylename = "Normal" )

doc = addSlide( doc, "Title and Content" )
# add a plot into doc 
doc = addPlot( doc
            , function() plot( rnorm(10), rnorm(10) )
)

# write the doc 
writeDoc( doc, pptx.file )
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to work with .ppt? Otherwise you could look into packages such as `knitr` which are meant to facilitate dynamic reports with `R`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the question ["How to embed a shell and browser into a presentation?"](https://superuser.com/questions/473700/how-to-embed-a-shell-and-browser-into-a-presentation) is a good start.

I think once you got a browser in powerpoint you are pretty free to work with R.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mac OS X, perhaps you can use [AppleScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript) to control both [R](http://ftp.auckland.ac.nz/software/CRAN/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#AppleScript-support) and [PowerPoint](http://techfleck.blogspot.com/2009/08/mac-powerpoint-scripting.html). (If you use Windows, there might be a similar scripting option that you could research.)

Comment: ??? I don't see anything in the question about his or her platform? Nor have I suggested anyone buy anything?